# Opening an HTML to a specific anchor within an HTML from another HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xslt-1.0

I wasn't really sure how to describe my problem in the title, but essentially I have a program that takes a certain file type and creates a bunch of HTML files that are displayed by different frames in a main HTML.  When a certain link is clicked on that page it opens another main HTML which has two frames.  I want to open the HTMLs in those new frames to a specific anchor, but I'm creating the main HTMLs through an XSLT stylesheet so I don't really have a way to give the main HTMLs (the ones that just have frames) a way to open to specific anchors.  I know that query strings exist, but I'm not really sure how to use variables with javascript.

Right now I have been trying something like this:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var this.variable = Request.QueryString["loc"];
document.write('<frameset cols="20%,*">
<frame name="actions" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" src="function_block_definition+__50C72C94_29973668__-actions.html"/>
<frame name="expression" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" src="function_block_definition+__50C72C94_29973668__-details.html#'this.variable'"/>');
</script>
</html>
```

But of course this doesn't work, or even display anything...  I also tried just doing the variable in the script and then trying to reference it outside, but I can't seem to find how to do what I want to do.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var this.variable = Request.QueryString["loc"];
</script>
<frameset cols="20%,*">
    <frame name="actions" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" src="function_block_definition+__50C72C94_29973668__-actions.html"/>
    <frame name="expression" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" src="function_block_definition+__50C72C94_29973668__-details.html#this.variable"/>
</frameset>

</html>
```

(loc is my query string and I'm trying to set whatever loc is equal to in the URL to the frame "expression" as an anchor name.  Neither does what I want and the page that I'm trying to reference with a specific anchor does scroll enough so I should be able to see if it works or not.

Comment: Do you have an example? Because maybe your frame isn't heigh enough, therefor your browser doesn't scroll to the anchor

Comment: Edited. When it opens without the anchor I have to scroll down to see so if it does work then I should see it work.